# Set minimum characters limit per line in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

- I want to set the limit min. 5 characters per line and
- I want to show message if `multiline` `textbox` have less than 5 `chars`. line.

Here is my code.

```
string[] temp = Regex.Split(KeywordList.Text, "\r\n");
for (int i = 0; i < temp.Length; i++)
{
    if (temp[i].Length <= 4) //check characters limit
    {
        Response.Write("Please enter min 5 characters per line");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("success");
    }
}
```

My textbox contains min. 5 characters in few lines but above code show **"success"**.

Can anyone help me to detect less than 5 characters row.

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Are you sure that your text lines are separated by "\r\n"?  I threw the code into LinqPad and set the KeywordList to a few lines, and it produced correct results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*: `Split` the initial string (please, do not put *magic values* like `"\r\n"`, but `Environment.NewLine`) and check if `Any` item is `4` characters or less:

```
   if (KeywordList
         .Text
         .Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
         .Any(item => item.Length <= 4)) 
     Response.Write("Please enter min 5 characters per line");
   else
     Response.Write("success");
```

In your current code `Regex.Split` is an *overshoot* (`String.Split` is enough), and it seems that you should add `break` after `Response.Write("Please enter min 5 characters per line");` line:

```
   ...
   if (temp[i].Length <= 4) //check characters limit
   {
      Response.Write("Please enter min 5 characters per line");

      break; // <- we have an error, no need to check more lines
   }
   ...
```

**Edit**: If you are not sure in delimiters (they can be `\n` - Unix, `\r\n` - Windows, `\n\r` - Mac etc.) you can try *several ones* in one call

```
   if (KeywordList
         .Text
         .Split(new char[] {'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
         .Any(item => item.Length <= 4)) 
     Response.Write("Please enter min 5 characters per line");
   else
     Response.Write("success");
```

However, we have to eliminate *empty items*: for `"a\r\n\b"` we want `["a", "b"]`, not `["a", "", "b"]`

Comment: I don't know why but "item.Length" count whole text of textbox (not per line)

Comment: @Narender Godara: we `Split` the string and obtain an array. If it contains *one* item only, it seems that you have a *wrong delimiter*. Do you really use `"\r\n"`, or just `"\n"`?

Comment: Replaced "\r\n" to "\n" and working properly. Thanks Dmitry Bychenko.